# why is spring boot opening a lot of connections?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm using a cloud database at elephantsql.com. As I'm using a free plan I can have only 5 concurrent connections.

I have a spring boot application that connects with this cloud database. The problem is that even when there is just one user at the website the spring boot application opens a lot of connections and some times it exceed the 5 connections.

I checked the connections at elephantsql.com and got this:

[image: connections stats]

Its seems that the following unnecessary query is increasing the amount of connections...

```sql
SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'
```

How could I fix this to avoid the application to open unnecessary connections?

Comment: You can use the connection pool option. you could customize many additional settings. the reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is probably
`spring.datasource.max-active=5`

Default value of this property is 10.